# Filter data by keywords and note where they were found

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

so i have a query at the moment.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
```

It yields besides other stuff 4 colums which contain text "Textbox1" "Textbox2" "Textbox3" "Textbox4".

I now want to filter this query by keywords in those text boxes. Basically the user can enters 0 to 5 keywords and the rows from TABLE1 should only show if at least one keyword was found in one of the textboxes. Also a new column should be added that for every keyword that was found in a textbox should say which keyword and in which textboxes it was found.

The query itself will later run in SSRS which is where the user puts in the keywords. So the keywords are accasable as varchars. For the query you can use this:

```
DECLARE @Keyword1 AS VARCHAR(100) = '';
DECLARE @Keyword2 AS VARCHAR(100) = '';
DECLARE @Keyword3 AS VARCHAR(100) = '';
DECLARE @Keyword4 AS VARCHAR(100) = '';
DECLARE @Keyword5 AS VARCHAR(100) = '';
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

[image: Example with desired result]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What if one of your keywords is found in multiple textbox columns?  What if multiple keywords are found in a single OR multiple textbox columns?

Comment: I added a picture that hopefully shows desired result and example data. I choose numbers in here just for examples but in the data itself there is text. 

If the keyword is found multiple times it should show all the textboxes in which it was found. If multiple keywords are found in the same box it should show for every keyword where it was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **very unelegant** solution and it's not exactly what you wanted but hopefully close enough.

*To improve it, especially if you are goning to extend this to more column/keywords I would consider unpivoting the data, testing each row and then aggregating the result of that back up again.*

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (T1 varchar(100), T2 varchar(100), T3 varchar(100), T4 varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 11, 203, 30),
(8898, 54452, 1222, 12122)

DECLARE @k1 varchar(100) = '1'
DECLARE @k2 varchar(100) = '22'

SET @k1 = '%' + @k1 + '%'
SET @k2 = '%' + @k2 + '%'

SELECT 
    *
    , CASE WHEN T1 like @k1 THEN '1:T1 ' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN T2 like @k1 THEN '1:T2 ' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN T3 like @k1 THEN '1:T3 ' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN T4 like @k1 THEN '1:T4 ' ELSE '' END +

      CASE WHEN T1 like @k2 THEN '2:T1 ' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN T2 like @k2 THEN '2:T2 ' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN T3 like @k2 THEN '2:T3 ' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN T4 like @k2 THEN '2:T4 ' ELSE '' END 
      As Found
    FROM @t
```

This give the following results.
[image]

Comment: So with the help of your answer i found a good solution. I split the cases by textboxes to get a new column for every textbox. 

I also removed the Set from the start and put them in the case because in ssrs you can not run two query statements. I also included a , after every find and a check if all parameters are empty which then should yield the the unfiltered list. 

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. However, in SSRS you can execute as much code as you like. I have scripts 100's of lines long sometimes. The only thing that matters is that it will only output the first recordset set, so you cannot have 2 simple SELECT statements. The script I posted was all in my dataset query.

Comment: Weird, i got an error with the set. But i found a workaround so it doesnt really matter that much.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Alan Schofield i found the solution that i need.

```
SELECT * from( Select*,
 CASE WHEN Textbox1 like '%'+@Keyword1+'%' AND @Keyword1 <> '' THEN @Keyword1 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox1 like '%'+@Keyword2+'%' AND @Keyword2 <> '' THEN @Keyword2 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox1 like '%'+@Keyword3+'%' AND @Keyword3 <> '' THEN @Keyword3 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox1 like '%'+@Keyword4+'%' AND @Keyword4 <> '' THEN @Keyword4 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox1 like '%'+@Keyword5+'%' AND @Keyword5 <> '' THEN @Keyword5 +', '  ELSE '' END  
      As Textbox1found,


      CASE WHEN Textbox2 like '%'+@Keyword1+'%' AND @Keyword1 <> '' THEN @Keyword1 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox2 like '%'+@Keyword2+'%' AND @Keyword2 <> '' THEN @Keyword2 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox2 like '%'+@Keyword3+'%' AND @Keyword3 <> '' THEN @Keyword3 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox2 like '%'+@Keyword4+'%' AND @Keyword4 <> '' THEN @Keyword4 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox2 like '%'+@Keyword5+'%' AND @Keyword5 <> '' THEN @Keyword5 +', '  ELSE '' END   
      As Textbox2found,

      CASE WHEN Textbox3 like '%'+@Keyword1+'%' AND @Keyword1 <> '' THEN @Keyword1 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox3 like '%'+@Keyword2+'%' AND @Keyword2 <> '' THEN @Keyword2 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox3 like '%'+@Keyword3+'%' AND @Keyword3 <> '' THEN @Keyword3 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox3 like '%'+@Keyword4+'%' AND @Keyword4 <> '' THEN @Keyword4 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox3 like '%'+@Keyword5+'%' AND @Keyword5 <> '' THEN @Keyword5 +', '  ELSE '' END
      As Textbox3found,

      CASE WHEN Textbox4 like '%'+@Keyword1+'%' AND @Keyword1 <> '' THEN @Keyword1 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox4 like '%'+@Keyword2+'%' AND @Keyword2 <> '' THEN @Keyword2 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox4 like '%'+@Keyword3+'%' AND @Keyword3 <> '' THEN @Keyword3 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox4 like '%'+@Keyword4+'%' AND @Keyword4 <> '' THEN @Keyword4 +', '  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Textbox4 like '%'+@Keyword5+'%' AND @Keyword5 <> '' THEN @Keyword5 +', '  ELSE '' END
      AS Textbox4found

      FROM Table1)as Result
      WHERE Result.Textbox1found <> '' OR Result.Textbox2found <> '' OR Result.Textbox3found <> '' OR Result.Textbox4found <> '' or (@Keyword1='' AND @Keyword2='' AND @Keyword3='' AND @Keyword4='' AND @Keyword5='')
```

I switched to a Textbox based query which will generat for every textbox a column with the keywords found in that textbox.